# Making a responsive web page

Tags: css, responsive

I am working on responsive web. I have an image that have content in front of that image. But, when I zoom out or zoom in to the max width, I found that the content ( in this case is text ) did not place on its first spot.

Do you have any idea how to make a web more responsive ? I mean responsive in here is whether we zoom in or zoom out, the position will be the same but the size maybe change.

Any idea will be appreciated. Big Thanks!
*I already am using bootstrap

Here the example of the code:

```
<div class="image-one">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg" style="padding:5px"/>
        <h2 style="vertical-align:middle;margin-left:150px;margin-top:-150px;position:absolute;color:#ff0000">Kuta</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I have a clue what you're asking, but take a look at this for a more responsive structure:

```
    <div class="image-one" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg" style=" max-width:100%; ">
        <h2 style="vertical-align:middle;left: 31.5%;top: 50%;position:absolute;color:#ff0000;">Kuta</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: wow men, how could you do that ? can u give me some reference about this. It working, thanks

Comment: Well, to break it down:

- The image will set it's width automatically, so by setting max-width:100%, we ensure the image cannot be wider than the screen
- The H2 was absolute, buy you didn't use top/left positioning, but you used margins to position (the point of absolute positions is to use top/bottom/left/right attributes). By setting these positions to percentages, they maintain their position (roughly) on screen size change.
- Also, the div had to have position:relative; to ensure it's absolute children position relative to it.

Look up position and max-width on w3schools.

Comment: okay, but when I minimize the screen or zooming it out/in, the size text does not following the screen. That is another problem that I got. How to change the text's size automatically based on the screen width. Thanks

Comment: Indeed - for zooming, the font size should change accordingly, but for screen resize, you may want to read up on css media queries - they are very easy to use, and supported by pretty much all browsers (not old browsers like ie8 though). You can use media queries to affect the font at certain screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what´s your issue exactly. You want the text and/or the image rezie? Maybe this will help you:

```
<div class="image-one" style="background-image:url('http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg');background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;  position: relative;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
        <div class="centered_text" style="position: absolute;top: 50%; left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%);">
            <h2 style="color:#ff0000">Kuta</h2>
        </div>
</div>
```